# How to properly use phpcs for checking all php files on project directory

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7, phpcs

I want to perform a check for **all** php files in my project directory to see if they are compatible with PHP 7.

I installed PHPCompatibility as a phpcs standard and I realised that variations such as .class.php, .lib.php .inc.php
were skipped using only `--extensions=php` or not specifying any `--extensions` as per the examples bellow

1) No --extensions

```
phpcs -p -s -v --standard=PHPCompatibility  /Users/natalisilverio/Sites/php7/ --runtime-set testVersion 7.0  --report-file=phpcs-noExtensions.txt
```

2) --extensions=php

```
phpcs -p -s -v --standard=PHPCompatibility  /Users/natalisilverio/Sites/php7/ --runtime-set testVersion 7.0 --extensions=php --report-file=phpcs-phpExtensions.txt
```

3) Multiple --extensions

```
phpcs -p -s -v --standard=PHPCompatibility  /Users/natalisilverio/Sites/php7/ --runtime-set testVersion 7.0 --extensions=php,inc.php,lib.php,class.php --report-file=phpcs-multipleExtensions.txt
```

If I target a specific directory that has an .class.php file and set --`extensions=.class.php` as an extension I get it listed on my report

```
phpcs -p -s -v --standard=PHPCompatibility  /Users/natalisilverio/Sites/php7/ --runtime-set testVersion 7.0 --extensions=class.php --report-file=phpcs-classExtensions.txt
```

I have many 3rd party plugins and I cannot tell which variation they would be using, so I would like to know which is the correct way to correctly check my project folder **recursively without setting multiple extensions** variations for .php files